# Flink Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.shaded.calcite.com.google.common.base.Throwables

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using Flink for streaming the data which is in the csv file. I want to put it into table format with certain schema. For this purpose I am using Flink-table_2.10-1.1.3.jar (Table api) but I got the errors:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/shaded/calcite/com/google/common/base/Throwables
    at org.apache.calcite.rel.metadata.JaninoRelMetadataProvider.create(JaninoRelMetadataProvider.java:450)
    at org.apache.calcite.rel.metadata.JaninoRelMetadataProvider.revise(JaninoRelMetadataProvider.java:460)
    at org.apache.calcite.rel.metadata.RelMetadataQuery.revise(RelMetadataQuery.java:186)
    at org.apache.calcite.rel.metadata.RelMetadataQuery.collations(RelMetadataQuery.java:484)
    at org.apache.calcite.rel.metadata.RelMdCollation.project(RelMdCollation.java:207)
    at org.apache.calcite.rel.logical.LogicalProject$1.get(LogicalProject.java:122)
    at org.apache.calcite.rel.logical.LogicalProject$1.get(LogicalProject.java:120)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.RelTraitSet.replaceIfs(RelTraitSet.java:238)
    at org.apache.calcite.rel.logical.LogicalProject.create(LogicalProject.java:116)
    at org.apache.calcite.rel.logical.LogicalProject.create(LogicalProject.java:108)
    at org.apache.flink.api.table.plan.logical.Project.construct(operators.scala:90)
    at org.apache.flink.api.table.plan.logical.Project.construct(operators.scala:85)
    at org.apache.flink.api.table.plan.logical.LogicalNode.toRelNode(LogicalNode.scala:78)
    at org.apache.flink.api.table.Table.getRelNode(table.scala:66)
    at org.apache.flink.api.table.StreamTableEnvironment.translate(StreamTableEnvironment.scala:243)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.table.StreamTableEnvironment.toDataStream(StreamTableEnvironment.scala:147)
    at table_streaming_test.main(table_streaming_test.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.shaded.calcite.com.google.common.base.Throwables
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 17 more
```

When I explore the corresponding jar, the respective class is present there. Can you please tell that why this is happening?

Also can I get the maven source so that I can build the Flink-table .jar at my place?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with CEP library. I added to my pom file but I kept getting ClassNotFoundException. I even packaged it with my jar file via IntelliJ but didn't work.

1. If you're using their flink-quickstart archetype, I think there are some other things to change in pom file to make it work. When I created a clean project and added flink dependencies myself, I didn't get that exception anymore. You can try and see if this approach works.
2. You can also add flink-table JAR file to `lib` folder in Flink. this also fixed my problem with CEP library. the JAR file is available in Maven repository website. download the version you want.

According to the `Table and SQL` document on Flink website:

> Note: The Table API is currently not part of the binary distribution.
>   See linking with it for cluster execution [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.1/apis/cluster_execution.html#linking-with-modules-not-contained-in-the-binary-distribution).

Comment: Can you please put your pom file here, so that I get an idea about changes and dependencies.

Comment: @kadsank Just create an empty Maven project on IntelliJ and copy the dependency tags from Flink's download page
http://flink.apache.org/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem with Table api in flink v1.4.2.

I added **flink-table_2.11-1.4.2.jar** file present in **opt** folder to the **lib** folder and restarted flink. 
This works for me. Hopefully works for you too :)